# plotfit.fd is upset about my names. Cannot plot and cannot understand error

Tags: r

Shot in the dark but I cannot get a plot function to work in the CollocInfer package. I am trying to execute the following code:

```
plotfit.fd(temps, times, DEfd1,nfine=N,
xlab="Time (hours)", ylab="Temperature level (metres)",title="")
```

I have my code working perfectly up until this point. When I execute I get the following error:

```
Error in checkDim3(x, y, xdim[id], ydim[id], dNi, subset, xName = xNmi,  : 


Can NOT subset subscript 1 of DEfd1$coef because some dimnames(subscript 1 of temps)[[xdim=2]] are not found in dimnames(y)[[ydim=2]];  the first one is temps
```

I've been trying to track down what this means for hours. I ran some pacjkage supplied code and tried to figure it out and couldn't. The documentation for the checkDim3 function is here: http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/misc/fda/downloads/FDAfuns/R/R/checkDims3.R

I looked at the data and the values are consistent, i.e. I solved the ODE I am trying to model and the parameter estimates are correct. Somewhere I made an error in the bookkeeping? Any help appreciated. Or a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, lesson learned:

```
dimnames(temps) <- NULL
```

works. This particular plotting function has tests for the dimnames of inputs.